# View dentro de View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá, eu estou pegando um código para dar continuação e gostaria de solucionar um problema.

1. eu tenho um CRUD de clientes, e dentro das views, tem o arquivo cliente_endereco...

Fui observar e me deparei que existe também uma model, cliente_endereco.rb...

Eu gostaria de implementar essa parte de enderecos no mesmo CRUD do cliente, então acredito que a melhor maneira seja um render partial, como esse talvez?

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: "customer_address_fields", locals: { customerAddress: @customerAddress }%>
```

A minha dúvida é essa, como utilizar o mesmo CRUD e salvar em outra tabela com outro model?

No Controller, no método def create, eu fiz o seguinte.

```
@customerAddress = CustomerAddress.new(customer_params)
```

Eu estou com problemas para criar um form dentro da view do endereço.
Acredito que não esteja carregando a view neste código.

```
<%= form_with(model: customerAddress) do |form| %>
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O rails já tem essa funcionalidade, se chama "Nested Attributes"

https://share.atelie.software/rails-nested-attributes-com-has-many-42ecf6179871

https://onebitcode.com/cocoon-nested-attributes-no-ruby-o-rails/